# How to split the string using python and perform operations?

Tags: python

This is the given string to split:

```
Succinate({3: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 1}) initial_feed_Glutamate_C32145_Glutexc_aKG_C34251_0.5*(CS)
```

What I want:

```
Eg: [Succinate], [{3: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 1}], [initial_feed_Glutamate_C32145_Glutexc_aKG_C34251_0.5*(CS)] should be outcome.
```

After the above output, perform the following operations on it:

1. From the dictionary above, filter the whole given string with values 1 in it.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: format your question properly please.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO and particularly about good [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure! @Ev.Kounis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think regex will come handy (python3 version)

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re

def main():
    '''The Main'''
    data = 'Succinate({3: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 1}) initial_feed_Glutamate_C32145_Glutexc_aKG_C34251_0.5*(CS)'

    res = list(re.match(r'^(.*)\(({.*})\)(.*)', data).groups())
    dic = literal_eval(res[1])
    print(dic)
    print(dic[3])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
{3: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 1: 1}
1
```

Comment: Why did you use ast in the import statement? 
What is "1" in 2nd line ? @krishna

Comment: for `literal_eval`. I used it later in the code to convert string to dict

Comment: Will this re work for any string like "Succinate" followed by dictionary?

Comment: It should work for any string. Please try your samples and let me know if it doesn't. It can be adjusted. Please explore regex it is fun